# Installing apps to phone storage

Tags: installation

version 4.4.2.
I have storage as follows.

Internal storage-1GB(full)
Phone storage-12GB(empty)

External sd card-16GB.

Now the internal storage is full, can i install my apps directly to phone storage(12GB)? If so how?

Comment: What ever happened or what ever manufacturer built your device: they did it wrong. Android 4.4 shares internal and phone storage so your manufacturer might have changed something. If you like to move apps to your phone storage, try moving them to your SD card. In recent versions of Android your "SD card" is your internal SD card meaning your phone storage.

Comment: But if i unmount my external sdcard,there appears no option to move.

Comment: The topic install location for the application (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install ) will help you.